# How should I automate graph generation and image output in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, automation, mail-merge

I am trying to send graphs of data to email recipients.

I would like to output images of row-specific graphs based on cells in a Google Sheets document. In combination with Google Sheets/Drive, I am using a mail merge add-on (YAMM) that can insert row-specific image files and need the graph images output to a directory with a public URL.

This is the most concise series of actions required to output the image file and make it accessible to the mail merge application.

Action to Automate:

- Select a range of cells in a row
- Create a graph based on that range of cells including key and labels
- Save image file of that graph in a public location
- Insert link to image file in sheet where cells are located
- Repeat on next row until blank

I am having difficulty tracking down resources on what tool to use to automate this series of actions. I would like to know if Google Apps Script is what I should be using to perform this automation. If not, is an alternative - including other add-ons or web apps - for this use case? Is there a different tack I should be taking with the data outside Sheets?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

Comment: See also: [Ways to learn google apps script language?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87006)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do all of this with Google Apps Script, though it's a pretty large project that arguably should not be someone's first project with GAS. Here is an overview of methods involved, with pointers to documentation.

1. Select a range of cells in a row:  [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)).
2. Create a graph based on that range of cells including key and labels: see [Embedded Chart creation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart), [Setting chart type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder), and customizations such as [EmbeddedBarChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-bar-chart-builder).
3. Save image file of that graph in a public location. The only place you can save is Google Drive, as follows:

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  // grabs active sheet
 var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];   // grabs the first chart on the sheet
 var file = DriveApp.createFile(chart.getBlob());   // saves it as a file
```

You get a PNG file named chart.png; this file can be renamed with [`setName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setName(String)) and [made public as follows](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access):

```
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
```

4. Insert link to image file in sheet where cells are located. Use [getUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getUrl()) to get the URL of the file. Add it to the sheet with [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)). Example:

```
sheet.getRange(5, 3).setValue(file.getUrl());   // automatically linked
```

You can make the link look fancy (with custom text) using `setFormula('=hyperlink('+file.getUrl()+','+ your_text + ')')` instead of setValue.

5. Repeat on next row until blank. Sure, that's what `for` and `while` loops are for, among other things such as [`getDataRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange())

Comment: Thanks for the level of detail; this should really be helpful for anyone looking to automate this, in addition to this GAS first-timer.